# ORA-00906 Missing left parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl

I have just started using Oracle SQL and have come across an error

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

My code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(    
dept_id varchar2(4), PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL,
Dept_name varchar2(30), NOT NULL, 
Manager_id varchar2(4));
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I go about fixing it? 
As I am expecting a table to be created with 3 columns (dept_id, Dept_name, Manager_id)

Comment: Too many `,` here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the comma (`,`) between column type definitions and the `not null` definitions. This can be resolved quite easily, dy dropping them. Additionally, as `primary key` implies `unique not null`, you can just drop the redundant `not null` clause on `dept_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
dept_id varchar2(4) PRIMARY KEY, -- here
Dept_name varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
Manager_id varchar2(4)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much the code works now and my table has been created! I shall mark this answer as correct as soon as SO allows me to (in approximately 6 minutes)